# How to pass STDIN to node.js child process

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I'm using a library that wraps `pandoc` for node. But I can't figure out how to pass STDIN to the child process `execFile...

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
var optipng = require('pandoc-bin').path;

// STDIN SHOULD GO HERE!
execFile(optipng, ['--from=markdown', '--to=html'], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
});
```

On the CLI it would look like this:

```
echo "# Hello World" | pandoc -f markdown -t html
```

**UPDATE 1**

Trying to get it working with `spawn`:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var optipng = require('pandoc-bin').path;
var child = cp.spawn(optipng, ['--from=markdown', '--to=html'], { stdio: [ 0, 'pipe', 'pipe' ] });

child.stdin.write('# HELLO');
// then what?
```

Comment: just in case someone is using IPC and JSON serialization, what I observed is that it sends message from Child-to-Parent but not Parent-to-Child using `send()` function. When I used `fork` instead of `spawn`, it started sending messages in both ways.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var optipng = require('pandoc-bin').path; //This is a path to a command
var child = cp.spawn(optipng, ['--from=markdown', '--to=html']); //the array is the arguments

child.stdin.write('# HELLO'); //my command takes a markdown string...

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
child.stdin.end();
```

Answer (score 20):

Like [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), [`execFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) also returns a [`ChildProcess`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) instance which has a [`stdin`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin) writable stream.

As an alternative to using [`write()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) and listening for the [`data`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) event, you could create a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams), [`push()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding) your input data, and then [`pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) it to `child.stdin`:

```js
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
var stream   = require('stream');
var optipng  = require('pandoc-bin').path;

var child = execFile(optipng, ['--from=markdown', '--to=html'], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
});

var input = '# HELLO';

var stdinStream = new stream.Readable();
stdinStream.push(input);  // Add data to the internal queue for users of the stream to consume
stdinStream.push(null);   // Signals the end of the stream (EOF)
stdinStream.pipe(child.stdin);
```

Answer (score 14):

## String as STDIN

If you are using synchronous methods (`execFileSync`, `execSync`, or `spawnSync`) you can pass a **string as stdin** using the `input` key in options. Like this:

```
const child_process = require("child_process");
const str = "some string";
const result = child_process.spawnSync("somecommand", ["arg1", "arg2"], { input: str });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure its possible to use `STDIN` with `child_process.execFile()` based on these [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/v6.2.0/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin) and the below excerpt, looks like its available only to `child_process.spawn()`

> The child_process.execFile() function is similar to child_process.exec() except that it does not spawn a shell. Rather, the specified executable file is spawned directly as a new process making it slightly more efficient than child_process.exec().

Comment: @emersonthis follow the docs link I posted in the answer and it shows how to in a code snippet.

Comment: @emersonthis update your question with your `child_process.spawn()` code, maybe another set of eyes will help?

Comment: Have you tried adding the options to `child_process.spawn()` `{ stdio: [ 0, 'pipe', 'pipe' ] }`?

Comment: Yes. I updated the code in the question with that. I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of null` no matter what I do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could solve this myself if I could see a single working example of passing STDIN to a child process... either a link to the docs or even just a code snippet. Anything would help

Answer (score 1):

stdin could be pass into `exec` and `execFile` with the `ChildProcess` instance.

```js
const { exec } = require('node:child_process');

const child = exec('cat', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
});

child.stdin.write('foo');
child.stdin.end();
```

reference: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/25231