# Run nodejs in sandbox with virtual filesystem

Tags: node.js, sandbox, virtualfilesystem

I am working on a project of online python compiler. When user sends a python, Server will execute it. What I want do is,create a sandbox with virtual filesystem, execute that script instide it, and that sandbox should far from real-server's filesystem, but nodejs should be able to control stdin and stdout of that sandbox.

How to make it possible?

Comment: Please, take an example.

Answer (score 1):

[Docker](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application) is a great way to sandbox things.

You can run

```
docker run --network none python:3
```

from your node.js server. Look at other [switches of docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) to plug in as many security holes as possible.

The shtick is, you run the docker command [from your node.js server and pass the user's python code via stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686259/10678955).

Now, if your node.js server is on one machine and the sendbox should run on another machine, you tell docker to connect to the other machine using the [`DOCKER_HOST` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables).

> Docker containers wrap up the software in a complete filesystem that contains everything it needs to run: code, runtime, system tools, system libraries — basically anything you can install on a server. This guarantees that it will always run the same, regardless of the environment it is running in.

This might be worth to read https://instabug.com/blog/the-difference-between-virtual-machines-and-containers/