# How can I modify a node bin script at runtime?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

There is a package which is a command line utility script. It uses the [prompts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompts) library to display questions and then performs actions based on the answers.

I want to run this script programmatically. I can see that the prompts library exposes an `overrides` method to let answers be set programmatically, but I do not have access to the source of the script to add this functionality in. Also, the script does not export any functions so it cannot be wrapped in another script.

How can run the script in a way that lets me set `prompts.override()` ?

Comment: doc exemple for override use it in combination with cli program arguments, maybe your cli original dev have also used it in that way ? https://github.com/terkelg/prompts/blob/master/readme.md#override

Comment: If you know the order of the questions and the answers you want to give, you can use `child_Process.exec` and provide the stdin to that child process from your wrapper script like shown in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685461/how-to-pass-stdin-to-node-js-child-process

Comment: "_There is a package which is_...": This is very mysterious. Show us (and link us to) the actual code!

Comment: @jsejcksn the code is internal

Comment: @Dan Can you  be more explicit? Can you provide an example of what tou want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code:

```
const prompts = require('prompts');
prompts.override(require('yargs').argv);

(async () => {
  const response = await prompts([
    {
      type: 'text',
      name: 'twitter',
      message: `What's your twitter handle?`
    },
    {
      type: 'multiselect',
      name: 'color',
      message: 'Pick colors',
      choices: [
        { title: 'Red', value: '#ff0000' },
        { title: 'Green', value: '#00ff00' },
        { title: 'Blue', value: '#0000ff' }
      ],
    }
  ]);

  console.log(response);
})();
```

How @emersonthis managed to add stdin to the `child_process`:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var optipng = require('pandoc-bin').path; //This is a path to a command
var child = cp.spawn(optipng, ['--from=markdown', '--to=html']); //the array is the arguments

child.stdin.write('# HELLO'); //my command takes a markdown string...

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
child.stdin.end();
```

You can implement something similar to this, but you **have** to know the order you want your answers and questions to appear as.

Relevant sources:

- [How to pass STDIN to node.js child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685461/how-to-pass-stdin-to-node-js-child-process)
- [Prompts package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompts)