# Github Cli Command does not work with express js

Tags: node.js, express, github-api

In my backend express server , I am trying to execute a github cli command using execSync. But it hungs up there. The command is following:
`

```
execSsnc("gh auth login --web")
```

`

In the same machine, when I use terminal to execute the same command, it works fine. In fact, I have tried a executing this line of code in a simple nodejs project and this too works fine. But whenever I use this in my express server, it hungs up there. I have tried using **spawn, exec, spawnSync** too but no luck so far.
Also when I use  `execSync("gh auth status")` this gives error saying there is no github hosts currently. But in the machine, when I run this command from the terminal, it says that I am already  logged it using Personal Access Token. Thus I found that running the login command from the express server is the main issue. Is there any way out?

Answer (score 1):

First, check if setting [`GH_DEBUG`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_help_environment) to `1` or `api` generates any verbose log which might shed some light to the issue.

```
const env = {
    'env': {
         'GH_DEBUG': 'api',
         ...process.env
    }
}

exec('gh auth login --web', env, function (error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout, stderr, error);
});
```

Second, check with another `exec` who you are when executed from Express.js, and compare it to your command-line environment (where it does work)

Using [`gh auth login --token < aTokenFile`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) (passing the token as [stdin to your execSync call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53633034/6309)) might be a better alternative than `--web`.

Comment: Thanks, the second method worked for me.

Comment: @jaintapauljp Perfect, well done.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `execSync` create a new shell and executes `gh` command in this shell.

Depending on the OS, the shell used by `execSync` might be different than the shell used in your terminal (bash/sh) or miss some env variables that are available in your terminal. This might explain why `"gh auth status"` execution shows different results.

Try to verify if the environment variables is your Express app are different than environment variables in your terminal